# Which geo service (if any) can return lat-long of the city center and the city radius given the name of a city?

Tags: geolocation, geospatial

I am looking for a concrete example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313607/finding-the-center-point-of-a-city, for instance, contains general information, which does not advance me much)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was recently discussed over at [GIS.SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com).  Take a look at [Maxmind Free World Cities Database](http://www.maxmind.com/en/worldcities) and geonames, among others noted in the questions linked below.

- [Comprehensive list of Latitude and Longitude values of cities round the world](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21923/comprehensive-list-of-latitude-and-longitude-values-of-cities-round-the-world)
- [Is a Country/State/City Database available?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/603/is-a-country-state-city-database-available)

Comment: -1: Doesn't answer the "city-center" part of the question. All the listed databases address a comprehensive list of city/zipcodes/latlong, but none of them have a list of city-center lat-longs or address how to calculate it from the comprehensive list.

Comment: Wow, @JavidJamae, did you really downvote an **accepted** answer from over a year, that was the _only_ answer?  On top of that, maybe you should do a little actual research of the sources of data it links to.  In fact, it **does** answer the "city-center" question, which is part of the [MaxMind Free World Cities Database](http://www.maxmind.com/en/worldcities).  This data includes (quoted from the website), "city, region, country, latitude and longitude."

Comment: I looked through a few of the Maxmind downloads, but had only seen the one with all the zip codes (which doesn't give you city-center latlong, just zipcode-center latlong). Neither your post or any of the links you provided linked directly to that specific database that you put in your comment, hence the downvote. I've edited the answer to link to it and changed my vote to an upvote. Thanks.

Comment: Was able to download lat / long data in CSV format from:  http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/csv/ .. As a result, upvoting edited answer .. Wasn't able to find "city radius" however in this particular data set